# Final Hardware Selection Step in Landscape Openstack Install

Tags: maas, openstack, landscape, openstack-autopilot

I'm on the last step before my Landscape Openstack install should begin. Configuration is chosen and 5 machines (KVM virtual machines managed by MAAS) are selected. (green checkmark)

But, the last step - Add at least one machine on the public network remains grayed-out and I don't see any way to select the last system.  I'm assuming the last system is the MAAS KVM machine with the two ethernet NICs.

If I add the 6th system along with the required 5, that does not help.

How can I get through this last step?

Have I incorrectly set something on Open vSwitch where a public network is set up?

How does this process work?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not 100% sure, but I made a new network in MAAS called public and added the 2nd NIC from all my dual NIC'd computers in MAAS that are on that network. (I have 3)  Then in landscape's Open vSwitch configuration I chose this 'public' network.

It got me past that step, don't know if it works correctly as I found your post since I was having the same issue.  I just clicked on the install button a min ago.

Comment: That was definitely worth a try - name my network "public".

Comment: But no luck. I have 6 systems I select and add.  One of then has 2 virtual NICs, with one NIC on the MAAS network and the 2nd bridged to my main LAN, which is "public".  Still stuck on the final "Add one machine on the public network". Did you install work?

Comment: I've the same problem anynews for you?